# Feed theme variables to new Modules system

Tags: css, sass, dart-sass

I work on styles for multi-tenant application for which the choice has been made to use SASS. Following the latest version guidelines, I started building base styles using `@use` and `@forward`. Now I want to **theme** this base with customers' colors and fonts variables to receive multiple stylesheets that can be served to different instances of our application.

If I was to use deprecated `@import`, I would go like this:

```css
styles/customerA/index.scss

@import "customerA-variables";
@import "../base/index";
```

But with new rules I cannot find an easy way to simply feed theme specific variables to the base styles. I tried to use `with` keyword, but it turns out I need to define variables in a module, while I would rather encapsulate them in another module and import it.

```css
styles/customerA/index.scss

@use "customerA-variables" as variables;
@use "../base/index" with (
  $bgColor: variables.$bgColor,
  $textColor: variables.$textColor
);
```

```css
styles/base/_base-variables.scss

$bgColor: #eee !default;
$textColor: #333 !default;
```

```css
styles/base/index.scss

/* HOW IT WORKS */
$bgColor: #eee !default;
$textColor: #333 !default;

/* HOW I WISH IT WORKED */
@use "./base-variables" as *;

/* LATER IN THE FILE */
body {
  background-color: $bgColor;
  color: $textColor;
}
```

In `@use "../variables" as *` scenario I get this error:

```
Error: This variable was not declared with !default in the @used module.
```

I'm looking for a working solution preferably without copy-pasting all theme variables inside `with` parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

**First the error:**

> Error: This variable was not declared with !default in the @used module.

That error arises when you try to `@use` a module/file with configuration variables but the configuration variables are not set as `!default` variables in the module/file. So, SASS checks if you are passing a configuration which is not provided to be configurated for the module. That's additional security to you.

I am not quite sure if I did understand your example right, but it could be the way:

```
// styles/customerA/index.scss

@use "customerA-variables" as variables;
@use "../base/index" with (
  $bgColor: variables.$bgColor,
  $textColor: variables.$textColor
);

--> SASS ERROR because $bgColor and/or $textColor
--> in @used module/file are not set as defaults, i.e.:
--> $bgColor: green;
--> must be: $bgColor: green !default;
```

So, you may check the module if the variables are all set to defaults and not overwritten by  non-default values.

**SECOND: usage of `@use`:

The new rule `@use` indeed is really confusing ... in your example that leads to doubled code: once when you set the custom vars in `customerA-variables.scss` and then when you repeat that variables when you `@use` the module/file in `styles/customerA/index.scss` (see your second code example).

A good way to avoid that doubled code is to prepare a configuration file with the settings for the individual customer and THAN `@use` the configuration file (not the wanted module/file direct).

Example:

```
// ###
// ### module/file: ../base/index.scss

$bgColor: #eee !default;
$textColor: #333 !default;

body {
  background-color: $bgColor;
  color: $textColor;
}



// ### 
// ### customer configuration file: configModuleCustomerA.scss

@forward "../base/index" with (
  $bgColor: red,
  $textColor: blue
);



// ###
// ### use that configuration file 
// ### to your main file: styles/customerA/index.scss

@use "...path.../configModuleCustomerA" as *;

// Note:
// 1. that writes the configurated css
// 2. and it provides the variables for additional use to THIS file
// see going on this file below ...

.additionalElement {
   background: $bgColor;
   color: $textColor;
}
   
   
// ### 
// ### ---> that compiles to CSS:

body {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
} 

.additionalElement {
   background: red;
   color: blue;
}
```

**NOTE: there is an additional TRICK/EFFECT you should know.**

YOU ONLY NEED TO SET THE VARIABLES ONCE ... just the time when you config the module/file. And as you do it in a/the module config file the variables you set there are part of you project configuration!

So, if you need the SAME variables of a module a second/third/... time (i.e. in additional partials files) you `@use` that configuration file in any file where you need it/them. Don't worry: the css code is only compiled ONCE to your CSS: the first time you `@use` the module.

**BUT HEAD UP IN YOUR CASE:**

But if you want to `@use` a module/file with different configurations as in your case you have to compile it into two DIFFERENT CSS files. One module with two or more different configurations loaded to the same CSS is blocked by SASS. In that case you need to split the css to different customer css files which all uses different module configuration files.

Comment: 1. **Error** I added `_base-variables.scss` snippet to the original post for clarification. So you can see,  I have declared variables with `!default`, but somehow it's lost when imported with `@use`.

Comment: 2. Do you know a way to have base variables stored in a separate file instead inlined in `module/file: ../base/index.scss`? Also, how can I past an object to `with` argument, instead long list of `($var: value ...)` ?

Comment: Error: troubleshooting can be a desperate process ... and I BELIEVE that you wrote the vars in the file as `!defaults`. But nevertheless the error and HINT from that error is clear: your tried to use a module/file with configuration vars ... but the configurations var don't exist in the module/file at all or as defaults. Maybe it's the way you include the var file: `@use "./base-variables" as *;` It's the same directory(!?), so maybe try `@use "base-variables" as *;`... or is it on another use of `@use`?

Comment: Store config vars in separate file: No.I did not found a working way up to now, but many hints that that is unwanted by the SASS project developers ... the heaven know why.  I think there are a lot of coders looking for ... But indeed in the docs there is a silk thin hint to pass an object (=map) by an mixin ... but the module must be prepared for it with mixins and I cannot realize the advantage to the module config file ... and it seems not to be practicable as well. But maybe that silk floss helps you: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#with-mixins (feedback would be nice)

Comment: Hi! Facing same challenges in 2024. Any good patterns/solutions to this? I'm refactoring import architecture to modular and don't want to rewrite all of the codebase with mixin approach.