# sass how to override variable values?

Tags: css, sass

I would like to override variable values from local.scss file in global.scss file.

```
/local.scss
$color-primary: #ffffff !default;
$color-secondary: #fffeee !default;

// global.scss
@use 'local' with (
$color-primary: #fefefe,
$color-secondary: #f4f4f4
)
```

This way I keep getting error `This variable was not declared with !default in the @used module`.
What do I do wrong here?

Comment: `!default` is not a keyword, you mean `!important`?

Comment: @AbinThaha https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#configuring-modules From what ive understood I can use 'default' flag to make it customizable

Comment: Ok. Got it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67000672/dart-sass-feed-theme-variables-to-new-modules-system. Does this fixes your error ?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't. The error still stays the same, no matter which approach I will take.

Comment: @AbinThaha Nvm, it worked out. Seems like my IDE was heavily lagging and thats why it kept showing me the same error all the time.